# AttributeError: 'WandbLogger' object has no attribute 'log_image'

Tags: python, logging, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, wandb

I'm using Wandb logger to log some images inside the validation step of my model.
Here is the code that I have used that,

```py
if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
    grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(front_img)
    imgs = [i for i in front_img[:8]]
    wandb_logger.log_image(key='front_image', image=imgs)
```

When I remove this line Wandb logs all the other parameters.

But when I tried to log the images i get this error saying,
[image]

But the documentation sayes there is a `log_image` attribute in `WandbLogger`.
Anyone knows the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `wandb.Image(`) and `wandb.log()` to log images? For example:

```
if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
    grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(front_img)
    imgs = [wandb.Image(i) for i in front_img[:8]]
    wandb.log({"front_image": imgs})
```

Comment: No this didn't work either. I moved to tensorboard for the time being

Answer (score 0):

can you give more context here? What framework are you using? What format the images are?

```py
# cast imgs to wandb format
# I am assuming tensors of shape (3, h, w) here
imgs = [wandb.Image(tensor_img) for tensor_img in front_img[:8]]

# log imgs to the workspace
wandb.log({"samples": imgs})
```